# VB.Net Is there a CancellationToken equivalent for pausing?

Tags: .net, vb.net, task

I want to add support to stop, pause, and resume a task, so I wanted to extend the CancellationToken object and add a flag IsPauseRequested similar to IsCancellationRequested.  I'm not able to Inherit from CancellationToken, so what is the best way to achieve this?

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class frmDebugTesting

    Private cts As CancellationTokenSource

    Private Sub StartButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click
        Task.Run(Sub()
                     cts = New CancellationTokenSource
                     Dim foo As New Foo
                     foo.DoWorkA(cts.Token)
                 End Sub)
    End Sub

    Private Sub PauseButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PauseButton.Click
        'cts.Pause()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ResumeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResumeButton.Click
        'cts.Resume()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StopButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StopButton.Click
        cts.Cancel()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Foo
    Public Sub DoWorkA(ct As Threading.CancellationToken)
        For i = 0 To 100000
            Debug.WriteLine(i)
            'If ct.IsPauseRequested Then
            '    ct.mre.WaitOne()
            'End If
            If ct.IsCancellationRequested Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        Dim bar As New Bar
        bar.DoWorkB(ct)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Bar
    Public Sub DoWorkB(ct As Threading.CancellationToken)
        For i = 100000 To 0 Step -1
            Debug.WriteLine(i)
            'If ct.IsPauseRequested Then
            '    ct.mre.WaitOne()
            'End If
            If ct.IsCancellationRequested Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How about a workaround and use a variable?

Comment: @muffi Can you give an example?  "Use a variable" is so vague :(  I get it you mean a boolean flag...

Comment: You could use two `CancellationToken` instances, possibly generated by separate `CancellationTokenSource` objects or both by a derived class of your own that adds that functionality.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Good idea, I'll give that a shot.  Specifically the latter part of your suggestion.  Thanks

Comment: @David yes, I would try to use a boolean.